# Как запустить jetty сервер в eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

Обьясните кто нибудь , что такое "Dynamic Web Module" и как с ним работать
Сколько искал, нигде не нашел никакой инструкции по тому, как можна работать с этим в еклипсе.
Изначально проблема в том, что я не могу запустить простой сервер jetty, сделав все так, куак сказано здесь
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld
Вроде бы все запускается , но страничка по адресу http://localhost:8080 не грузится.
Нашел статью, где рассказывают, как запускать jetty, и вот так используют 
"Dynamic Web Module"
Помогите, расскажите, подскажите, как запустить jetty на Eclipse, и поподробнее
.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Web Module - это приложение, которое имеет динамически создаваемые страницы - чаще всего сочетание Servlet и JSP. Название на мой взгляд путающее - проще было бы просто назвать - Web Application и не морочить всем голову.

По поводу Jetty - проще всего наверно установить плагин Run-Jetty-Run.
Зайти в меню: Help -> Install New Software.
Выбрать URL http://run-jetty-run.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite
и там уже дальше устанавливать.
При создании проекта в разделе Run появится Run Jetty и Run Configuration, в котором можно установить Jetty. Надо там обратить внимание на значение в поле "Context" - при запуске доступ до приложения будет такой:
localhost:8080/ContextValue

Для начала можно посмотреть тут: java-course.ru/student/book1/servlet/